# Visual Studio Run Code Button shifted in the three dots

Tags: java, visual-studio

The visual studio run code is should as default like this

[image]

But, I don't know why this is showing for me in the .JAVA files.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The run code button isn't there by default (or at least it did not show up for me by default). It is actually an extension called "Code Runner", you can find it in the extensions:marketplace tab.